ASP.NET Core app on Nginx does not use .css files
I would like to run asp.net core app on my local Linux-server (Ubuntu 22.14 LTS). I have successfully installed the .Net Core SDK 8.03 and installed Nginx as a reverse proxy. While testing the configuration with a very simple WebApp (generated in VS2022), I noticed the following:

when starting dotnet  from the cli 'sudo dotnet testapp`, all runs well, and the landing pages is rendered with all the css-markup.
when running the app as a service, the app itself runs, but no css-markup whatsover is applied. I assume the wwwroot-folder is not properly accessible.

How can i make sure that the wwwroot-folder and subfolders are accessed and the pages load including their css-markup?
kestrel-app.service
[Unit]
Description-ASP.NET Core Web App running on Ubuntu

[Service]
Workingdirectory=/var/www/testlinuxapp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/testlinuxapp/TestLinuxApp_Sec.dll
Restart=always
# restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SysLogIdentifier=dotnet-web-app
# this user should exist onthe server and have ownershipof the deployment directory
User=appuser
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Nginx configuration file to enable the reverse proxy
server {    listen        80;
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}


Did you compile the css? What exactly are the errors in console? Are there any other static images or something that ARE accessible in the wwwroot?

Hi Marcel,  I use a default minified css (bootstrap.min.css). I included an image in wwwroot and it did not show, although the tag is recognized (broken link icon)

Sorry everybody. I found the type in the Kestrel-App.service. The typo was SysLogIdentifier= instead of SyslogIdentifier=
